# How do I show only one paragraph at a time using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I want to hide one paragraph after opening another paragraph using jQuery. I also want paragraphs not to flick when the page loads or when we refresh it.

None of the close solutions solved the problem.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is the snippet(updated).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("p").hide();

    $("#btn1").click(function(){
         $("#p1").toggle();
    });

    $("#btn2").click(function(){
         $("#p2").toggle();
    });

    $("#btn3").click(function(){
         $("#p3").toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="btn1" class="button"><a href="#">About</a></div>
<p id="p1">Some text.</p>

<div id="btn2" class="button"><a href="#">Story</a></div>
<p id="p2">Some text.</p>

<div id="btn3" class="button"><a href="#">Summary</a></div>   
<p id="p3">Some text.</p>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you require you should show a single button and genericise the HTML of the `p` elements. On each button click you can then retrieve the first visible `p` element. From that you can target the next hidden `p` and display it while hiding the previous one. Something like this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.button').on('click', () => {
    let $visible = $('p:visible');
    let $target = $visible.next('p:hidden');
    if ($target.length) {
      $visible.hide();
      $target.show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
p { display: none; }
p:first-of-type { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="button"><a href="#">Next</a></div>
<p>First Paragraph</p>
<p>Second Paragraph</p>
<p>Third Paragraph</p>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: It's useful. However, I need to preserve all buttons. You can get a better understanding with my updated snippet.